# bitwise or on class objects

Tags: python, qt, pyside, bitwise-or

How using **Bitwise OR** operator in **`item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditableQtCore`** in the following code prevents `item.flags` from being overwritten? I know how Bitwise OR works on numbers but i can't make sense of its use here:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("cleanLooks")

    #Data
    dataList = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

    #Creating item based QlistWidget
    listWidget = QtGui.QListWidget()
    listWidget.addItems(dataList)
    listWidget.show()

    #Make all items of the listWidget editable
    count = listWidget.count()
    for i in range(count):
        item = listWidget.item(i)
        item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)

    #Creating item based QComboBox
    comboBoxWidget = QtGui.QComboBox()
    comboBoxWidget.addItems(dataList)
    comboBoxWidget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: If you know how bitwise OR works, then you should know getting the current flags and then OR it with a new flag, will create a new flags value with the original flags + new flag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These flags are stored as powers of 2, so they are for example `1, 2, 4, 8, ...`. If you convert these into the dual base you see them as `0001, 0010, 0100, 1000, ...`.

If you now have the flag value `item.flags()` and combine it with the bitwise or `|` with `QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable` you are creating a new value, which has (as an example) this dual base representation:

```
flag:           10001100 
ItemIsEditable: 01000000
------------------------
result:         11001100
```

So it is just the normal bitwise or operator, between an integer number and the integer values of the `Qt` enum
[image]

This means especially, that if the `item.flags()` value has stored some flags already, you can add more flags with this `|` operator, without unsetting/overwriting the information of the previous set flags; this allows you to store information about multiple flags in just one integer value.